# Self-adjointness of the Sturm-Liouville operator problems

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble with this question. Could you please help me?
Let $f$ be differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$ and $f(0)=0$

$$
Ly=(f(x)-2x^{3})\ddot{y}+(5x^{4}e^{x^{3}}+3x^{2}f(x))\dot{y}+f(x^{2})y
$$

What should $f(x)$ be for $L$ to be self-adjoint?

I know that $Ly=a_{0}\ddot{y}+a_{1}\dot{y}+a_{2}y$ equation must be $a_{1}=\dot{a_{0}}$ using Lagrange identity for it to be self-adjoint, but I could not apply it for this equation.

Comment: $\dot{a}_0=a_1\implies \dot{f}-6x^2=5x^4e^{x^3}+3x^2f$. To find $f$, solve this differential equation.

Comment: Thank you, noticed when I saw your answer.I made a simple mistake. I used $6x$ instead of $6x^{2}$